# Get location (lat/long) from googlemap with address - Using powershell

Tags: google-maps, powershell

I would like to create a script that allow myself to get the coordinates of some locations on Google map using their addresses. 
To do this I use powershell code:

```
clear-host

$address = "Place+de+la+concorde"
$city = "Paris"
$cp = "75000"
$country = "France"

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + $address + "+" + $city + "+" + $cp + "+" + $country
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
Write-Host = $result
```

Unfortunately I can not retrieve rows interesting to me, ie:

results> geometry> location> lat

and

results> geometry> location> lng

Any idea for getting a specific line information, considering that the number of lines could change ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConvertFrom-JSON is the cmdlet you need.

```
$json = Invoke-WebRequest $url | ConvertFrom-JSON
$json.results.geometry.location.lat
$json.results.geometry.location.lng
```

Now you are looking at a JSON object (as intended) rather than lines so you won't have to worry about line position, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you !I already found a method using xml but I'll use yours.