# How to calculate the distance between different cities by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am doing a project which needs to calculate the distance between different cities in the world.  I think there is a way with google maps, but I do not know how to use it within PowerShell.

I found something new from [Get location (lat/long) from googlemap with address - Using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25240612/5038177).

The answer to that question is quite useful, but the coordinates I got can't be directly used to calculate the distance. 
I've tried to use `[Single]`,`[Int]` or`[Double]` to change the data type. But it gave me the error `Cannot convert the "System.Decimal" value of type "System.RuntimeType" to type "System.Double".`

Any method can convert the data type?

Comment: @wOxxOm Now there is a new problem. The data type cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the conversion part of this question (using the example from the other question you referenced), the following will give you a decimal variable:

```
$lat = $json.results.geometry.location.lat
```

This will convert it to a double (for example):

```
$lat = [double]$json.results.geometry.location.lat
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I just found out why I cannot do the calculation. I used 'BIrmingham' as one of the cities, but there are two different 'Birmingham' on the earth. One in the U.S. and the other one in the UK. I think that is the reason for my error. But still thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tools that will help you work with Google Maps in PowerShell

1. [The Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)
2. The [GoogleMap Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/GoogleMap/1.0.0.0) from the PowerShell Gallery
3. The [math] class which will let you perform advanced mathematical calculations in PowerShell. The MSDN documentation for this is great, but it's not written for PowerShell, so it helps if you know a little VB or C.

Comment: Any method to the new question?