# Get values of httpresponse using batch file

Tags: batch-file

For example I have this HTTP Response:

```
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 51.0,
    "lng": -0.1
  },
  "accuracy": 1200.4
}
```

How do I get only the values 51.0 and -0.1? I tried doing it with this:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (foo1.tmp) do (
    echo %%a >> url.tmp
)
set /p lat=<url.tmp
more +1 <url.tmp >new.tmp
for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (new.tmp) do (
    set var2=%%a
)
```

I was able to get the first value which was 51.0 but for the second value which as var2, I am getting the 1200.4 value which is supposed to be -0.1. Any help here?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25240612) and [associated PowerShell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247066) provide you with a better/more sensible solution to your task?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %A in ('findstr "lat lng" ^<foo1.tmp') do @set "%~A=%B"` in a batch file double the percent signs -> `%%A,%%B`

Comment: So doe sit mean that %%A corresponds to the latitude while %%B corresponds to the longitude?

Comment: Never mind your answer worked @LotPings thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better explain what my one liner from the comment does:

```
findstr "lat lng" <foo1.tmp
```

filters lines containing either `lat` or `lng` using default regular expression mode, sample output:

```
    "lat": 51.0,
    "lng": -0.1
```

Instead of using a temporary file, you can directly use `curl/wget`

To process the output the `for /f` parses the line with the delimiters `:,` (colon,comma,space).
Leading delims are ignored, adjacent ones are counted as only one, so

%%A contains `"lat"` / `"lng"`
%%B contains `51.0` / `"-0.1"`

To strip the double quotes from %%A the for variable modifier `~` is used.

In summary the (batch) line:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %%A in ('findstr "lat lng" ^<foo1.tmp') do set "%%~A=%%B"
```

sets the variables

```
> set l
lat=51.0
lng=-0.1
```

Comment: Well I have a problem here. The time I first used your answer it worked and it printed the lat as 51.0 if called by %lat% and the same goes for %lng% however, when I run this code again it does not work. Any help on this one? Because I am certain that it works because I tested it but I tried it today a few times and if I run echo %lat%, it returns %lat% and not the value.